# facing issues in installing npm for node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm just getting started with ionic V2. When I tried installing npm for node.js I'm getting some errors which I could'nt resolve. I tried installing it in other machines and it was working fine. But in my work machine I'm getting this error,

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\io
nic\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for     fsevents@
1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:     {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"
})
npm WARN In ionic@2.1.18 replacing bundled version of cross-spawn with     cross-spa
wn@4.0.2
npm WARN In ionic@2.1.18 replacing bundled version of semver with     semver@4.2.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.1.18 replacing bundled version of mime-types with mime-types
@2.0.14
npm WARN In ionic@2.1.18 replacing bundled version of form-data with form-data@0
.2.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.1.18 replacing bundled version of request with request@2.51.
0
npm WARN In ionic@2.1.18 replacing bundled version of ionic-app-lib with ionic-a
pp-lib@2.1.9
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program     Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path     C:\Users\gowtham.ADS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\ans
i-09f7f7d4
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\gowtham.ADS\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\ansi-09f7f7d4' -> 'C:\Users\gowtham.AD
S\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\a
nsi'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\gowtham.ADS\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\ansi-09f7f7d4' -> 'C:\Users\gowtham.AD
S\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\a
nsi'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gowtham.ADS\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

EDIT1: inserting npm-debug.log,

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'list' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.9.4
4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\gowtham.ADS/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose stack Error: write EPIPE
5 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
5 verbose stack     at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:712:26)
5 verbose stack     at Socket._write (net.js:731:8)
5 verbose stack     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
5 verbose stack     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
5 verbose stack     at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
5 verbose stack     at Socket.write (net.js:658:40)
5 verbose stack     at Console.log (console.js:43:16)
5 verbose stack     at module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\output.js:6:15)
5 verbose stack     at ls.fromTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\ls.js:103:3)
6 verbose cwd C:\Users\gowtham.ADS
7 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
8 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "list"
9 error node v6.9.4
10 error npm  v3.10.10
11 error code EPIPE
12 error errno EPIPE
13 error syscall write
14 error write EPIPE
15 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
15 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: what's in `C:\Users\gowtham.ADS\npm-debug.log`

Comment: Hi @Alex, I have updated my question with npm-debug.log file. Thanks for reaching out though

Comment: are you installing npm, or running `npm install`?

Comment: running npm install @Alex for installing ionic framework

Comment: can you try disabling firewall / antivirus?

Comment: @alex I tried disabling my firewall and antivirus but still I'm getting that same error as before

Comment: You are having the problem I have. And it is your aplliocation is setup for MacOS only..I know, it sucks. Still trying to figure out how to remove that myself> See, your error says (fsevents@
1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:     {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"
}). Meaning it required OS for dependencies to install and run but your current is win32

Comment: @LOTUSMS I somehow managed to fix this issue by completely removing npm and node.js from the system including environment variables pointing to it and reinstalled it. Anyway thanks for raising your hand!

Comment: I feel your pain. I was coming to let you know I did the same. Glad it all worked out in the end. Good luck

Comment: I am using the Alpine docker (https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/3b038b8a1ac8f65e3d368bedb9f979884342fdcb/6.9/alpine/Dockerfile) and faced the same error. So, edited the docker file not to remove the  "&& apk del .build-deps \" build dependencies but rest all the same. and hence when the npm install was performed, it worked fine.